# Storing C# String Array in SQL Database

Tags: c#, sql, arrays

What would be the best way to accomplish storing a string array from C# in the SQL database my program is working with?

Specifically:

1. What datatype would I use for the SQL column that needs to store the string array?
2. In C#, what method do I need to use to convert the string array to be able to insert it into the SQL database?

It is not important that the string array is readable when looking at the database. I just need to be able to store it in the database, and pull it back into the C# program when needed.

Comment: Google sql datatypes and read up on the various types, there are a number that are used for storing text and it depends on what you want to do with it. You may or may not need to convert it based upon your the datatype of your column.

Comment: Your question is much too broad. The only suggestion is do not just save an array; it is a relational database, find a relation in data and set it up as such.

Comment: Sounds like a mis-design, but if you really need it, I would store it in a VARCHAR(MAX) in CSV format. Then you just use `String.Split` to get it back.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233843.aspx

Comment: The way to represent an array in any relational database is to use what relational databases do best: a **table** (and use a FK constraint to link it to the "parent" entity). Anything else is a kludge at best, and should be avoided

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An array represents a one-to-many relationship. Normally, you will create another table for this and store each string and the original table's primary key in it.

You could serialize the string array using XML or binary/base64, but be prepared that your database admin will look down on you as the developer who did not understand databases.

Comment: +1 Exactly - "array" in database terms is a separate **table**